# What exactly is a lexeme?

Tags: linguistics, morphology

In different books, I've encountered different examples:

LEAVE - leave, leaves, left, and leaving

TAKE - take, takes, took, taken and taking

BANK- the shore of a river   and   a particular kind of financial institution

What would we call a lexeme then?
*Leave*, *take* and *bank* - thinking about a lexeme in terms of a 'set of grammatical words'?

Or perhaps both the 'base' words and the inflicted forms (or the meanings), which are derived from them?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Professor David Crystal coined the term 'lexeme', and included multi-word single-concept signifiers (such as 'ship of the desert' = 'camel', 'put on' = 'don', 'fire engine').

Comment: The OED's first citation is from Benjamin Lee Whorf: 1940 _Lang., Thought, & Reality_ (1956) p.160: _C. F. Voegelin has accomplished the difficult and signal work of analyzing an immense number of baffling stem compounds of Shawnee into their component lexemes (stems) and other morphemes (formatives)_. Here's [a visual comparison](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf) of `Lexeme`, `Phonological Word`, and `Word-Form`, 3 different categories that are often merged in popular speech under the term _Word_.

Comment: Thank You for your help. Having this information in mind... Will the inflicted forms of a lexeme grammatical words?

Answer (score 2):

A lexeme is a lemma (what you called a “*'base' word*”) plus its inflected forms. In linguistic articles, you often find lexemes displayed as the lemma in small capital letters.

It's also useful to say what a lexeme is not:

- **not** derived words that aren't inflections. For example, the lexeme BANK (noun) consists of *bank* and *banks*, but not *banker*. BANKER is a lexeme of its own, consisting of *banker* and *bankers*.
- **not necessarily** related words. For example, the lexeme GOOD consists of *good*, *better* and *best*. The last two are not derived from *good*.
- **not** a semantic concept. Therefore, “*the shore of a river*” plus “*a particular kind of financial institution*” do not comprise the lexeme BANK.

Comment: I'm writing a blog post that touches on lexemes and just wanted to say that this is one of the best explanations I've found. Short and to the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> The OED's first citation is from Benjamin Lee Whorf: 1940 *Lang., Thought, & Reality* (1956) p.160: *C. F. Voegelin has accomplished the difficult and signal work of analyzing an immense number of baffling stem compounds of Shawnee into their component lexemes (stems) and other morphemes (formatives)*. Here's [a visual comparison](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf) of `Lexeme`, `Phonological Word`, and `Word-Form`, 3 different categories that are often merged in popular speech under the term *Word*.